# How can I get the TOP 1 from this GROUP BY result?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the TOP 1 result, for each grouped row, in my result set.

```
Id LogType CreatedOn
===============================
1  Red     2000-01-02T12:34:56Z
2  Red     2000-01-02T12:34:56Z
3  Blue    2000-01-02T12:34:56Z
4  Green   2000-01-02T12:35:56Z
5  Red     2000-01-02T12:36:56Z
6  Red     2000-01-02T12:37:56Z
7  Blue    2000-01-02T12:38:56Z
8  Green   2000-01-02T12:39:56Z
```

Expected results

```
LogType Count MostRecent
==================================
Red     4     2000-01-02T12:37:56Z
Blue    2     2000-01-02T12:38:56Z
Green   2     2000-01-02T12:39:56Z
```

[This has all been setup in this Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e4eb/2).

I've got the `COUNT` (that was easy) but i'm not sure how to get the most recent and then link it back to the previous results. I was thinking a `ROW_NUMBER() / PARTITION ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC` and filter by `= 1` .. but I'm stuck on the join.

Note: I'm using SQL Server 2012 if there's any questions about software particular keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Count() over(Partition by)` trick to do this.

`Over` clause will help you find the count of each `group(LogType)` then as you mentioned find the top 1 in each group using `row_number` window function.

```
select LogType, Count, MostRecent from 
(
select Row_number() over(partition by LogType order by CreatedOn DESC) RN,
       Id, LogType, CreatedOn as MostRecent,
       count(LogType) over(partition by LogType) [Count] 
       from yourtable
) A
where RN=1
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e4eb/4)**

Comment: TIL: You can do a `COUNT(..) OVER(PARTITION ...)`. I've always just done `ROW_NUMBER() OVER..`. :hi-5:

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
select LogType, count(1) as 'Count', max(CreatedOn) as 'MostRecent' 
from yourtablename 
group by LogType
order by Count desc
```